# Apache Spark merge two identical DataFrames summing all rows and columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two dataframes with identical column names but different number of rows, each of them identified by an ID and Date, as follows:

First table (the one with all the ID's available):

| ID | Date | Amount A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-09-01 | 100 |
| 1 | 2021-09-02 | 50 |
| 2 | 2021-09-01 | 70 |

Second table (a smaller version including only some ID's):

| ID | Date | Amount A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2021-09-01 | 50 |
| 2 | 2021-09-02 | 30 |

What I would like to have is a single table with the following output:

| ID | Date | Amount A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-09-01 | 100 |
| 1 | 2021-09-02 | 50 |
| 2 | 2021-09-01 | 120 |
| 2 | 2021-09-02 | 30 |

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you elloborate more on logic seems like in the output you don't want to do the sum over certain values for 1st dataframe for example, for 2021-09-01 you haven't done the some over the 1st record where AmountA is 100. Basically, i just want to know the logic when to invoke the sum method.

Answer (score 2):

### Approach 1: Using a Join

You may join both tables and sum on similar rows.

#### Using spark sql

1. Ensure your dataframe is accessible

```scala
firstDf.createOrReplaceTempView("first_df")
secondDf.createOrReplaceTempView("second_df")
```

2. Execute the following on your spark session

```scala
val outputDf = sparkSession.sql("<insert sql below here>")
```

```sql
SELECT
    first_df.ID,
    first_df.Date,
    first_df.AmountA + second_df.AmountA as AmountA
FROM
    first_df
LEFT JOIN
    second_df ON first_df.ID = second_df.ID AND
                 first_df.Date = second_df.Date
```

#### Using Scala api

```scala
val outputDf = firstDf.alias("first_df")
                      .join(
                          secondDf.alias("second_df"),
                          Seq("ID","Date"),
                          "left"
                      ).selectExpr(
                          "first_df.ID",
                          "second_df.Date",
                          "first_df.AmountA + second_df.AmountA as AmountA"
                      )
```

#### Using pyspark api

```py
outputDf = (
               firstDf.alias("first_df")
                      .join(
                          second_df.alias("second_df"),
                          ["ID","Date"],
                          "left"
                      ).selectExpr(
                          "first_df.ID",
                          "second_df.Date",
                          "first_df.AmountA + second_df.AmountA as AmountA"
                      )
)
```

### Approach 2: Using a Union then aggregate by sum

#### Using spark sql

1. Ensure your dataframe is accessible

```scala
firstDf.createOrReplaceTempView("first_df")
secondDf.createOrReplaceTempView("second_df")
```

2. Execute the following on your spark session

```scala
val outputDf = sparkSession.sql("<insert sql below here>")
```

```sql
SELECT
    ID,
    Date,
    SUM(AmountA) as AmountA
FROM (
    SELECT ID, Date, AmountA FROM first_df UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, Date, AmountA FROM second_df
) t
GROUP BY
    ID,
    Date
```

#### Using Scala api

```scala
val outputDf = firstDf.select("ID","Date","AmountA")
                      .union(secondDf.select("ID","Date","AmountA"))
                      .groupBy("ID","Date")
                      .agg(
                          sum("AmountA").alias("AmountA")
                      )
```

#### Using Pyspark api

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

val outputDf = (
               firstDf.select("ID","Date","AmountA")
                      .union(second_df.select("ID","Date","AmountA"))
                      .groupBy("ID","Date")
                      .agg(
                          F.sum("AmountA").alias("AmountA")
                      )
)
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: @carlos-casio Did this work for you?